# Use withCount method with some condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, lumen, laravel-5.8

I have a `musics_rate` table and a `musics` table:

```
musics_rate:
    music_id : integer
    user_id : integer
    rate_type : boolean
```

***Music model***:

```php
public function rates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'musics_rate');
}
```

Now I want to sort `musics` by `music_rates` where `rate_type==true` count (created in this week):

```php
Music::where('created_at','>=', Carbon::parse('last saturday'))
    ->withCount('rates')
    ->orderby('rates_count','desc')
    ->get();
```

But it sorts by all rates (positive rates and negative rates) count.

Is there a way to filter only positive rates.

Comment: you can add where condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the `music` models that have a positive `rate`:

```php
Music::whereHas('rates', function ($q) {
    $q->where('rate_type', true);
})
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse('last saturday'))
    ->withCount('rates')
    ->orderby('rates_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

If you want all `music` models but only load the positive `rates`:

```php
Music::with([
    'rates' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('rate_type', true);
    }
])
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse('last saturday'))
    ->withCount('rates')
    ->orderby('rates_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```